# Is it poor practice to set font-size CSS property to a 'vh' value?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Suppose the `font-size` attribute of an HTML text element, such as an `<h1>`, needs to be adaptive to the *height* of the page. A 'typical' way to handle this might be to write some breakpoints at fairly regular intervals and size the text down in each one. In order to be more dynamic, I've instead applied `vh` values to certain `font-size` properties instead.

As I haven't seen this method used much, I'm unsure if it could be considered a poor practice - meaning, if there are known issues or flaws with this method, specific browsers or devices that either don't support this value on `font-size` or will potentially handle the calculation unusually.

Comment: `vh` doesn't ensure to keep `height: 100%`. Post expected and what already you've done

Comment: @Hitmands: `vh` does what’s needed (which isn’t `height: 100%`). I’m not sure anything else *can* do it, either.

Comment: @Hitmands It seems like you think I'm encountering a bug. I'm not, I'm wondering if what I'm doing is a poor practice or not.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: CanIUse is a good resource, however I nonetheless wonder about using it to define a `font-size` property, as opposed to a height or margin. Regardless, even if it is supported, I still do want to ensure that it's an acceptable practice to define a `font-size` in that manner. Just because it's supported doesn't necessarily mean it's not poor practice.

Comment: I will try to reword this question in a more objective way, although I have my answer.

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: I have now read it - but I feel there's an important distinction here. I'm not asking if it is the 'best practice'. I'm asking if it is a _poor practice_. 'Best practice' is definitely an amorphous term that virtually everyone will disagree on in most cases, and is very specific - only _one_ practice can be 'best' in a given situation. But whether or not something is a _poor_ practice ought to be less argumentative and subjective, if there are known flaws with a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays using `vh` for font sizes is not  uncommon. But IMO you should only use it on big headers and similar texts (= *very large*  text), never on content text, since a size like `3.5vh` can become extremely tiny (and therefore unreadable) on a mobile device.